# cmd.exe: After redirecting stdout and stderr to a file, it still prints lines to the console window

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, windows-console

I have executed a .bat file under cmd.exe in Windows 10, and redirected the standard output and standard error to a file:

```
C:\MyFolder> Foo.bat 2>&1 1>x.txt
```

But it still prints some lines to the console window, and those lines are not written to the file.

- How is that possible? On what output are these lines, which print to the console window?
- How to redirect those lines to the file?

Comment: Console applications can open CONIN$ and CONOUT$ to directly access the console. Redirecting the standard handles has no effect on this.

Comment: You have to include a reproducible example. There's many ways in which applications can write to the console window without having any effect on standard I/O. If there is a problem you need to solve, you have to show how to cause the problem. Be specific.

Comment: @Luaan: I know, but I was not able to isolate a small example that I could publish. I have a huge build system, and a `make.bat` does this to me. This bat starts a lot of programs (jam, compiled C++, pl, py, java). I am happy with an answer in a general context. E.g. what methods are there to bypass stdout and stderr and still write to the console? I have all the source which does this and do not know what to search for.

Comment: If you can't find the culprit, we surely can't :) Isolate everything piece by piece, even if it means just breaking the script at different points until you find the first command that causes your problem.

Comment: Yes indeed. Apart from that I still think, that a general answer would be useful to the community. Let's collect all ways stdout and stderr can be bypassed (maybe in a community wiki answer). So far @ErykSun's comment with the [Console Handles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-handles) was the most useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to redirect `stdout` (`1`) and `stderr` (`2`) into the same file is to redirect them in *this exact order*:

```
C:\MyFolder> Foo.bat 1>x.txt 2>&1
```

This applies to Windows `cmd.exe`, but also to Linux `bash` shell.

In your version (in the wrong order) `stderr` is not redirected to the file, and gets printed in the console window. So most probably the lines, which appeared in the console window were printed to `stderr`.

Another way a program (probably called by `Foo.bat`) can bypass the file, is writing directly to the console's active screen buffer with [Console Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-handles) `CONOUT$`. This cannot be redirected to a file.